# Proving that a Turing machine decides a language in NP

Tags: complexity-theory, logic

Suppose a deterministic Turing machine T decides language L and L is in NP. Then must it be provable in ZF that T decides L?

Comment: How is L given? ​ ​

Comment: The title you have chosen is not well suited to representing your question. Please take some time to improve it; we have collected some advice [here](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/a/815/). Thank you!

Comment: OK, just changed it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, ZF does not prove that $T$ decides $L$, unless ZF is inconsistent.

Take e.g. $L$ to be the language of words having even length (which is in P, hence in NP).

Consider the TM $T$ which on input $w$, crafts the first $|w|$ proofs in ZF. 
If any such proof proves a contradiction, accept.
Otherwise, accept if and only if $|w|$ is even.

We note that $T$ decides $L$ if and only if ZF is consistent. So, if ZF can prove that $T$ decides $L$, it is proving its own consistency, hence by Godel's second incompleteness theorem ZF is inconsistent.